# How do you explain the Strong Sampling Assumption?

Tags: probability, statistics

When using the **strong sampling assumption**, we assume that our data points are drawn *uniformly* and *independently*.

In the example I recently saw we have a data set: $D = \{16, 8, 2, 64\}$. And we have two hypothesis; either the data is even, $h_{even} $, or the data points are powers of 2, $h_{power_2}$.

In the example:

$P(D\ |\  h_{power_2}) = (1/6)^4$

$P(D\ |\ h_{even}) = (1/50)^4$

$Likelihood\ ratio = \frac{(1/6)^4}{(1/50)^4}$

The reason for being able to calculate this that way was that we could use the *strong sampling assumption* which says that $P(D\ |\  h) = \frac{1}{|h|}^N$, where $|\ h\ |$ is the number of examples belonging to the hypothesis. My question is how we are supposed to conclude that $|\ h\ |$ is **6** and **50** in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have $6$ numbers as $2^x$ in the range $[0,100]$. For the same range you have $50$ even numbers. Since the probability of every number to happen is equal, you have $1/6$ for powers and $1/50$ for the even number. But I think your set must be restricted to $[0,100]$, else these probabilities will change.

*Murphy, Kevin P.*, Machine learning. A probabilistic perspective, Cambridge, MA: MIT Press (ISBN 978-0-262-01802-9/hbk; 978-0-262-30616-4/ebook). xxix, 1067 p. (2012). [ZBL1295.68003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1295.68003). Chapter 3. Section 3.2.1 Likelihood.

Comment: Yes, I remember being told about this range. I did not connect the dots. Thanks a lot!